# can ActorRef be used as Map key

Tags: scala

I was trying to use the ActorRef as key of Map, but this seems not a correct choice

with actor passed through context:

```
persistor = context.actorOf(persistenceProps)
```

the key value seems changed.

what is the reason ?

```
[case1-primary] Primary actor: Actor[akka://Step5PrimaryPersistenceSpec/user/case1-primary#533153706]
[case1-primary] Primary persi: **Actor[akka://Step5PrimaryPersistenceSpec/user/case1-primary/$a#728170290]**
[case1-primary] Primary sending persist message: Actor[akka://Step5PrimaryPersistenceSpec/user/case1-primary/$a#728170290] <- Persist(foo,Some(bar),0)
[case1-primary] Primary Retry message Persist(foo,Some(bar),0) -> Actor[akka://Step5PrimaryPersistenceSpec/user/case1-primary/$a#728170290]
[case1-primary] Persisted ack +1 **Actor[akka://Step5PrimaryPersistenceSpec/system/testActor3#-426557875]** 0
```

Tried using ActorPath, same thing: seems persistor  is not referenced but instead newly created in side Primary. don't know why

The message passing are all okay, its just the "key" is different makes my code treat them as different actor

Comment: Try using the `path` of the actor ref as the key to the map.

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html

Comment: I used it at the assignment and it did work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the abstract class `ActorRef` shows that it implements `hashCode` and `equals` as well as extending `java.lang.Comparable[ActorRef]`, so it should work fine as a key in both hashed and sorted maps as well as in hashed and sorted sets.